# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '64 А' to data type int

Tags: sql

При создании временной таблицы ошибки нет, но есть ошибка ниже

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#doble_fias') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #doble_fias
End
CREATE TABLE #doble_fias (
    rrgn_id int,
    vvillage_id int,
    hhouse_id int,
    nnb_house int,
    nnb_stroen Varchar (10) collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS,
    bbody Varchar (12) collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS,  
    sstreet_id int  
);
Insert Into #doble_fias
SELECT rgn_id,village_id,house_id,nb_house,nb_stroen,body,street_id
FROM house 
WHERE street_id =6177
UNION  
SELECT rgn_id,village_id,house_id,nb_house,nb_stroen,body,street_id
FROM house 
WHERE street_id= 1081
```

Ошибка при выполнении этого скрипта:

```
SELECT * FROM #doble_fias t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT nb_house,body 
  FROM house t2
  WHERE t1.nnb_house=t2.nb_house AND t1.bbody = t2.body  collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
  GROUP BY nb_house, body
  HAVING (count(nb_house)>1 AND count(body)>1)
)
```

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '64 А' to data type int.

Comment: и чего вам не ясно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: У вас в какой-то из ячеек значение `64 A`. А такое конвертнуть в `int` невозможно, вот и ругается

Comment: в `house.nb_house` видимо